# SQL Server 2008 : Where Clause with And Or

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this `WHERE` clause:

```
Where Year(CreateDate) >= '2016'
  and b.colors1 In ('Yellow','Red')
  Or  b.colors2 In ('Yellow','Red')
  Or  b.colors3 In ('Yellow','Red')
```

I only want to return `CreateDate >= 2016` but I'm getting data outside of '2016' because of the `Or` statement. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and year is Not String

```
Where Year(CreateDate) >= 2016
and (b.colors1 In ('Yellow','Red')
     Or  b.colors2 In ('Yellow','Red')
     Or  b.colors3 In ('Yellow','Red') )
```

Comment: Thanks. Essentially this searches the OR statements first and then grabs the CreateDate?

Comment: Order in where clause is followed for filtering data